Anonymous Functions Vs Classic Function
I'm not able to figure out the reason for this behavior, can any one help me understand
  let counter= (function (){
    let count = 0;
    return function() {
        count+=1;
        return count;
    }
})()

for (let i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    console.log(counter());
}

This prints an output of
 1
 2
 3

Where as the below code
 function increment() {
    let count = 0;
    return function() {
        count+=1;
        return count;
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    console.log(increment()());
}


Prints 1 1 1 1


Literally nothing to do with "anonymous" functions. Or classical ones. In the first case the outer function called once, in the second multiple times. In the second case a counter = increment() would have produced the same behaviour as the first code.

Every time you call increment() this also happens: let count = 0; - What you want instead if to first store the function as const inc = increment(); and than do console.log(inc()) inside the loop

In the first example, the closure is created once and reused, so the state (count) is maintained across calls.
In the second example, a new closure (and hence a new count variable) is created each time increment() is called, so the state is not shared across the loop iterations.

Is it because let counter is pre-initialized with a function where count = 1 ; But in the other case, as the function is called every time, it's resetting the count to 0

No, it has nothing to do with the initialization. I don't even see count = 1 in the code. Both snippets initialize the variable with let count = 0;.
